# What would be the proper connectors to use to enter the box?

Tags: electrical

Running 1 1/2 PVC with 2-2-2-4 inside to an 8x8x4 PVC J box to connect to 2-2-2-4 SER cable inside box.

Answer (score 1):

You'll use a 1 1/2" PVC male terminal adapter, to fit through the knockout in the box. Then a 1 1/2" locknut inside the box, to hold the terminal adapter in place.

[image]
[image]

For the SER cable, you can use a 1 1/2" cable clamp.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What about the 2-2-2-4 ser ? Can I run it in to the bottom of the box threw a 1 inch male adapter. I have been told SER cannot be run threw conduit - but I think a male adapter would be alright , just not sure.

Comment: @KathleenWeymouth, NO, the SER MUST terminate in a proper connector. I'd use a 1-1/4" SER connector. Like the one shown, only the bottom half of the "saddle" is rounded not flat.